torchvision models produce different outputs in eval mode when the batch size is different
With torchvision models, I found that different batch sizes produce slightly different outputs, even in eval mode.
At the first time, I found with example of torchvision.models.efficientnet_v2_s.
And also tried more light model torchvision.models.vgg11.
(And the difference is even more pronounced with efficientnet_v2_s model)
here is the code

model = torchvision.models.vgg11(weights = None).cuda()
model.eval()
model = model.features

inputs = torch.rand([128, 3, 128, 128]).cuda()

# small batch size
out1 = model(inputs[:2])

# largs batch size
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]



Can someone let me know the reason?
resnet :

efficientnet :


Add
test on cpu give same results but on gpu give different results.
Code on cpu:
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False

device = 'cpu'


model = torchvision.models.vgg11(weights = None).to(device = device)
model.eval()
model = model.features

inputs = torch.rand([128, 3, 128, 128]).to(device = device)

# small batch size
out1 = model(inputs[:2])
# large batch size
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]
print(torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)))

model = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)).to(device = device)
model.eval()
out1 = model(inputs[:2])
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]
print(torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)))

model = torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True).to(device = device)
model.eval()
out1 = model(inputs[:2])
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]
print(torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)))

model = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False).to(device = device)
model.eval()
out1 = model(inputs[:2])
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]
print(torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)))

-------------------------------------
tensor(True)
tensor(True)
tensor(True)
tensor(True)

Code on gpu
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False

device = 'cuda'


model = torchvision.models.vgg11(weights = None).to(device = device)
model.eval()
model = model.features

inputs = torch.rand([128, 3, 128, 128]).to(device = device)

# small batch size
out1 = model(inputs[:2])
# large batch size
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]
print(torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)))

model = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)).to(device = device)
model.eval()
out1 = model(inputs[:2])
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]
print(torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)))

model = torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True).to(device = device)
model.eval()
out1 = model(inputs[:2])
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]
print(torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)))

model = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False).to(device = device)
model.eval()
out1 = model(inputs[:2])
out2 = model(inputs)[:2]
print(torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)))

-------------------------------------
tensor(False, device='cuda:0')
tensor(True, device='cuda:0')
tensor(True, device='cuda:0')
tensor(True, device='cuda:0')


I ran your sample code on my CPU instead of on GPU and the tensors ended up being equivalent. I don't have a GPU to try it on at this moment, but I suspect that the GPU may have something to do with your inconsistent results.
torch.all(torch.eq(out1, out2)) is what I evaluated.

Please post the code and error as text, not screenshot.

@BrockBrown. Yes you are correct. I tested on both cpu and gpu. Cpu makes same results. I added results on the question.

I think I'm convinced these are floating point rounding errors. For example, 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 evaluates to False. Closer to this example, (0.1 + 0.2) + 0.3 is not equivalent to 0.1 + (0.2 + 0.3). My guess is that this has something to do with the order in which CUDA decides to do operations on floats when your inputs are different shapes.

Hey, I just saw someone on the Pytorch forum just ask the same question you asked here. ptrblck pointed them to the reproducibility docs to read about CUDA determinism.
